# XAMPP not compatible with MySQL on m1 mac

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, mysql-workbench, apple-m1

I am currently using XAMPP(ver 8.1.4) on my M1 macbook pro. I need to use MySQL Workbench(ver 8.0.28) However I constantly get an error when trying to get connection as root. I looked up on various posts about XAMPP and MySQL being problem but most of them points out that MariaDB in XAMPP uses port 3308 but currently I am on 3306 for both MySQL and XAMPP. Anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix this problem so I can use XAMPP and MySQL on my M1 macbook? This is the error message that I am getting.

[image: MySQL error message]

Comment: XAMPP delivers mariaDB not actually MySQL anymore

Comment: Are you saying that you have also installed an instance of MySQL seperately to what XAMPP delivers?

Comment: If you have, then just STOP the MySQL in XAMPP (which is mariaDB) and the other real MySQL will get access to port 3306, and it will be the real MySQL that you are talking to

Comment: You may have to restart the real MySQL

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am doing this for my assignment for my university, and even though it actually delivers mariaDB I heard that it is compatible with the MySQL. My professor have used MySQL Workbench on Windows and it does work. I just need to fingure out a way to do this same on m1 mac.

Comment: Well mariaDB was forked from MySQL in 2009. Ever since, they have been less and less alike while supposedly trying to keep a compatibility. Remember that while MySQL Workbench in windows may work, the code for MySQL Workbench on a MAC will not be the same. So you have multiple points where difference may cause you problems

Comment: I simply use the `continue anyway` option, even though I use MariaDB. At some point, as mentioned in other comments above, MySQL Workbench will eventually be unusable with MariaDB as the two DB's get more and more divergent from each other.

Comment: Thanks for the response guys I'll close the question for now as it seems incompatible.